# Recommend hex editor class for C#?

Tags: c#, hex-editors

I am looking for a free hex editor class/control for C#. Could you recommend a good one?

PS:  The only requirement is the control/class should support view/edit file as hex and should be as simple as possible if could.

To be more specific, there should be a interface support loadFile/createFile/saveFile.

I have a small file(less than 0.5k) that need to show in a text-box like control in hex.

Comment: What do you mean by asking for a "hex editor class"? What are the requirements? What is your goal you want to achieve?

Comment: @PVitt I think he wants a drop-in user control for either a WPF or Forms application (@Jichao - which?) that implements a hex editor: that he can feed data into and save the edited content.

Comment: @Rup: That's definitely what I want. I do know what's the different between WPF and Form application, but I am creating a C# Form Application.

Comment: Check out the code presented in the article [MFC Hex Editor Control](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/controls/mfc-hex-editor-control).

Answer (score 1):

Is [HexBox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/) the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: tried before and found it is a little complicated for me. I'll have to write my own open file/save file etc method. Anyway,+1 for your answer.